# Wordpress functions don't save

Tags: php, wordpress, function, settings

I am making a wordpress theme for free download.
I made some theme functions with `$wp_customize` what looks like this:

```
<?php
// theme options
function basilico_customizer_register($wp_customize) {
// Blog styling
$wp_customize->add_section('basilico_blog_styling', array(
    'title' => __('Blog styling', 'basilico'),
    'description' => 'Styling the blog'
));
$wp_customize->add_setting('main_color', array(
    'default' => '#1b9145',
));
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_color_Control($wp_customize, 'main_color', array(
    'label' => __('Edit main background', 'basilico'),
    'section' => 'basilico_blog_styling',
    'settings' => 'main_color'
) ));
$wp_customize->add_setting('background_pattern', array(
    'default' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/bg.png',
));
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'background_pattern', array(
    'label' => __('Edit background pattern', 'basilico'),
    'section' => 'basilico_blog_styling',
    'settings' => 'background_pattern'
) ));
// General settings
$wp_customize->add_section('basilico_general_settings', array(
    'title' => __('Change logo', 'basilico'),
    'description' => 'setting the general settings'
));
$wp_customize->add_setting('logo_image', array(
    'default' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/logo.png',
));
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'logo_image', array(
    'label' => __('Edit logo image', 'basilico'),
    'section' => 'basilico_general_settings',
    'settings' => 'logo_image'
) ));
}
function basilico_css_customizer() {
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .article_header,.button a,#bar1,#bar2,#bar3,thead th,.widget_title,#footer,nav ul li a:hover,nav ul li.current-menu-item > a,.nav-previous a,.nav-next a{
        background-color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('main_color'); ?>;
    }
    .single_article_author span,.single_article_author span a,.cbp-spmenu .menu-item-has-children:before,ol li,h1,h2,h3,h4,hr,a{
        color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('main_color'); ?>;
    }
    hr{
    border-top: 2px solid <?php echo get_theme_mod('main_color'); ?>;
    }
    #overflow_container,body{
    background-image:url(<?php echo get_theme_mod('background_pattern'); ?>);
    }
</style>
<?php 
}
add_action('customize_register', 'basilico_customizer_register');
add_action('wp_head', 'basilico_css_customizer');
?>
```

I tried to open my theme in a clean wordpress install, but all the defaults do not show..
Does someone know how to save these settings so the default settings show immediately after installing the theme.